# Residues of tanh(z)

Tags: complex-analysis

Compute the residues of all singularities of $\tanh(z)$ and compute the integral where $C$ is the circle of radius $12$ centered at $z_0=0$.

Work so far:
poles are $z=i\pi/2 +in\pi$

the residues of the poles are all $1$.

What i would like to know is which poles are inside the circle so i can compute the integral

Comment: Any attempts so far?

Comment: iv done the majority of the work just need to know which poles are inside the circle so i can use the formula 2ipi(summation of residues inside the circle)

Comment: You know exactly where the poles are, and their residues. For which $n$ are the poles inside the given circle?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Recall that $i\tanh(x)=\tan(ix)$ and that near $x=(k+\frac12)\pi$, $\tan(x)$ looks like
$$
\frac1{(k+\frac12)\pi-x}
$$
Thus, near $x=(k+\frac12)\pi i$, $\tanh(x)$ looks like
$$
\frac1{x-(k+\frac12)\pi i}
$$
Find for which $k$ these poles are inside a circle centered at $0$ with radius $12$.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you could could do that, 1) draw the circle of radius 12 and draw out the singularities. Or 2) solve for n algebraically, you know $ \frac{i\pi}{2}+in\pi<12 $ so you can set that equal to 12 and solve for n, this will give you the number of singularities on one half of the circle.